# How do I exclude files and directories from a project in vim (using janus)?

Tags: vim, macvim, ack, janus

I'm moving from Textmate to vim (with janus) and want to exclude some directories from Ack in particular, and also NERDTree.

The reason I want to do this is that Ack is useless (takes minutes to run, and produces no results) with one of my large projects which contains a directory full of marshalled db data (with many subdirectories and hundreds of thousands of files).

I know how to exclude files (not directories) from NERDTree, and also exclude patterns from CommandT.  Neither of these solve my Ack issue.

I'm a complete vim n00b.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: What options do you use for Ack? `--ignore-dir=nameOfDirectory` will ignore `nameOfDirectory`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> By default, ack only checks your ~/.ackrc file for it’s default
>   switches. You can have per directory ack settings if you add this to
>   your .bash_profile:

```
export ACKRC=".ackrc"
```

http://www.rustyrazorblade.com/2012/03/making-better-use-of-your-ackrc-file/

Comment: Actually ack looks in _multiple_ locations for .ackrc. Not just ~/.ackrc. Please refer to the ack documentation https://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-2.24-man.html#ackrc_location_semantics. It looks at all the locations, global, user and project.

Answer (score 4):

For NerdTree, use [`NERDTreeIgnore` setting](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L763).

as for Ack - you can set `--ignore-dir` flag in your `.ackrc` (as explained in Ack's man page)

Comment: Thanks.  So it's not possible to do exclude directories from Ack on a per-project basis?

Comment: You could create a wrapper script which sets ACK_OPTIONS per project basis, so it would be something like `ACK_OPTIONS=--ignore-dir=lolwut ack $1` and use it instead of `ack` command.

Comment: I think this is the best I can get.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I only had to create a `.ackrc` in my top directory with the following:

```
--ignore-dir=log/
```